# Richard Bass' Real Analysis for Graduate Students Exxample 11.5

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm currently taking a prelim sequence in Real Analysis and we're using Richard Bass' Real Analysis for Graduate Students and he has an example after proving Fubini's Theorem I'm trying to wrap my head around.  It reads:

> 11.5 There exists a set $X$ together with a partial order $"\leq"$ such that $X$ is uncountable but for any $y \in X$, the set $\{x\in X: x\leq y\}$ is uncountable.  The $\sigma$-algebra is the collection of subsets $A$ of $X$ such that either $A$ or $A^c$ is countable.  Define $\mu$ on $X$ by $\mu(A) = 0$ if $A$ is countable and 1 if $A$ is uncountable.  Define $f$ on $X\times X$ by $f(x,y)=1$ if $x\leq y$ and zero otherwise.  Then $\int \int f(x,y)\, dy\, dx = 1$ but $\int \int f(x,y)\, dx \, dy = 0$.

I understand that this is an example where Fubini's Theorem doesn't hold but I'm having trouble understand why the integrals equal what they do.  My basic understanding (which isn't very rigorous) is that if we integrate first with respect to $y$ over $X$ then we'll get that $\int f(x,y)\, dy = 1$ and that $\int 1 \, dx = 1$ and similarly we'll get $\int f(x,y) \, dx = 0$ and thus $\int 0\, dy = 0$, but I'm not sure as to why the base integrals equal 1 and 0 respectively.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing $x$, you have $\int f(x,y)\,dy = 1\cdot\mu(\{y:y\ge x\})$. Since $\{y:y\ge x\}$ is uncountable, $\mu(\{y:y\ge x\})=1$ and this integral is $1$. On the other hand, fixing $y$, you have $\int f(x,y)\,dx = 1\cdot\mu(\{x:x\le y\})$. Since $\{x:x\le y\}$ is countable, $\mu(\{x:x\le y\})=0$ and this integral is $0$.